# Cloudformation RDS Aurora : Invalid Storage Type

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Following is my CFD script to create an RDS instance.
I am trying to create Amazon Aurora with PostgreSQL compatibility, but I am facing: `Invalid Storage Type : gp2` error.

```
  SnapshotRDSDBInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      AllocatedStorage: 20
      DBInstanceClass: 'db.t3.medium'
      DBName: mydatabase
      StorageType: gp2
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      PubliclyAccessible: true
      MultiAZ: false
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref SnapshotRDSDBSubnetGroup
      VPCSecurityGroups: 
        - !Ref SnapshotRDSDBSG
      MasterUsername: 'test'
      MasterUserPassword: 'Demo@123'
      BackupRetentionPeriod: 15
      DBInstanceIdentifier: 'myrds'
```

I also tried to remove the `StorageType` parameter in above script , but then I face `Invalid storage type: standard` error.
I am not able to understand the root cause.
I am using `ap-south-1` (Mumbai) region to launch this script.

Comment: `StorageType` isn't needed for Aurora as mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55966646

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aurora instances need to be associated with a `AWS::RDS::DBCluster` via `DBClusterIdentifier` without the cluster you get these generic errors

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was wondering whether the same would hold true because some sections of the docs seemed to suggest this; but couldn't find a definitive answer in the docs. Do you have a link to the docs where this is stated?

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand your use case please clarify below questions

1. Are you trying to configure Aurora MySQL in Cluster mode which has Writer and Reader Instances.
2. Are you trying to create Aurora MySQL in Serverless.

If you are planning to go with option 1 then you need to first create a cluster using `AWS::RDS::DBCluster` and add Writer and Reader Instances using `AWS::RDS::DBInstance`.

If you are planning to go with option 2 then just use `AWS::RDS::DBCluster`

When you decided to go with either of the option with correct cloud formation resource, will eliminate your storage error.